# Find latest record for different products according to plant

Tags: excel, vba, database, excel-formula

I have a data base in Excel with the following structure:

[image]

I'm trying to make the following summary table:

[image]

So every time i **change the Plant** it shows the latest update (date) by product, in the example:
London was updated the 14th for Pasta with 9 units of stock, and the 10th for Bread with 13 units of stock.

Is there a way to do that? With VBA or a formula?

Notes:

1. My database is constantly changing (adding more data).
2. In the summary table, the Plant cell will change value according to the plant i want to analyze.

Comment: 1. Excel is not a database, there are better tools for that.  2. What have you tried? 3. Where and how did it fail?  Please see [mcve]

Comment: @ScottCraner 1. Sadly, i can't change that, they're working with Excel, at least for this topic. 2. I've seen people using Lookup function and other functions but always only with one parameter (in this case plant + product).

Comment: You are basically asking us to do this for you, that is not in scope for this forum.  We are here to help overcome specific problem with existing code. Not write it for you or teach you how or show you where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `LET()` assuming you're running the latest version of Excel, data is stored within a table, and the input plant is stored in `F2`.

This pulls a list of unique products sold by plant, then looks up their last updated date, and sums the stock of that product & plant on the last update date. The final `CHOOSE()` pulls it all together.

This returns a dynamic array of last updated products and stock.

```
=LET(
plant, F2,
products, UNIQUE(FILTER(DataTable[Product],DataTable[Plant]=plant)),
lastUpdate, MAXIFS(DataTable[Date],DataTable[Plant],plant,DataTable[Product],products),
sumStock, SUMIFS(DataTable[Stock],DataTable[Plant],plant,DataTable[Product],products,DataTable[Date],lastUpdate),
CHOOSE({1,2,3},lastUpdate,products,sumStock))
```

[image]